# Unethical to toggle bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is it unethical to programatically toggle BT on/off without user's permission each time? Does Google take down apps that do that? I see that it is made explicitly that user's permission should be given in order to toggle BT on/off in the guide, but how is it enforced?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The ethics is a gray area. You did declare you have permission, but you may want to put up a notification/warning of some sort.

From what I [read](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html). You have to declare permissions for things you access outside your application.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use Bluetooth at all you have to ask permission from the Android OS in your app's Manifest. I would imagine that if Google wanted apps to explicitly get user permissions it would do it automatically at this point.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't be turning it on and off like that, have a look at the [different states](http://www.swedetrack.com/images/bluet10.htm) a bluetooth device goes through to see if that helps you solve the problem.